# how to check request parameters not null in more simple way in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to check the request parameters not null,but in my code ,I think it maybe check twice ,so could everyone give me some improvement。and I pass parameter by address bar.
here is my code :

```
<%
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String name,password;

try {
    name = (request.getParameter("name") != null) ? request.getParameter("name") : "null";

    password = (request.getParameter("password") != null)? request.getParameter("password") : "null";
%>

<h3>name:<%=name%></h3>
<h3>password:<%=password%></h3>

<%
}catch (NullPointerException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: the passed parameters use this way:request.jsp?name=usre?password=0000

Comment: Why not just use   <h3>name:${param.name}</h3> and don't check for null.

Comment: @zfireear See my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply assigning a null value to a String won't have the effect of a NullPointerException thrown by Java, if that is what you mean by checking twice.

In your snippet of code, you have already implemented a logic to check against null values on name and password, by assigning to them the String literal "null" and thus having some kind of visual feedback when the Jsp is loaded.

```
name = (request.getParameter("name") != null) ? request.getParameter("name") : "null";

password = (request.getParameter("password") != null)? request.getParameter("password") : "null";

<h3>name:<%=name%></h3>
<h3>password:<%=password%></h3>
```

That said I would suggest to check those parameters against null within a Servlet and since you asked for suggestion let me add a couple of things:

First: you don't want to pass a password via GET method.

Second: scriplets are widely considered to be bad practice for maintainability and re-usability 
reasons. (MVC pattern is the way to go, but that's another topic).

Learn what they are and then move on: don't try and implement some complicated Java logic within a Jsp as you will see there are more powerful, cleaner and more useful techniques to make a Jsp dynamc like JSTL, custom tags and EL.

For instance assuming your ultimate goal is to provide the user with some kind of feedback you could have

```
<h3>name: ${name != null && name != "" ? name : 'not assigned' }</h3>
```

As said above you would probably want to check against null values in a Servlet and control the flow of your application from there (e.g. you could redisplay the form in case no values have been entered).
That would allow to simply have this on your Jsp

```
<h3>name: ${name}</h3>
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [String.valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method when you need to set `"null"` String for `null` objects :

```
name = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("name"));
```